# Web asp.net calling SQL stored procedure creating multiple sessions on SQL Server, occasionally, under heavy activity the web app fails

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Under heavy usages, the web app occasionally fails. When this happens the only error message I get is

> Stored procedure failed

The problem is it works 80 to 90% of the time and only fails when the website is getting multiple hits over a couple of minutes of time, say 150 from six different locations over a two minute interval.

We are using IIS Manager 6.2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 to host the intranet web app that is used for collecting time punches from six pi terminals. The app was created with Visual Studio 2017

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SLDB;Initial Catalog=SyteLine_AWP;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sqladmin")

Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

Dim parm As New SqlParameter()
Server.ClearError()

Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError

parm.Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
parm.ParameterName = "ReturnValue"
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm)

cmd.CommandText = "AWP_TimeClock_Web"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAR_badge_num", badgenum)
cmd.Parameters("@VAR_badge_num").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAR_term_id", TermID)
cmd.Parameters("@VAR_term_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters.Add("@VAR_emp_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = ""
cmd.Parameters("@VAR_emp_name").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.Parameters.Add("@VAR_error", SqlDbType.Int, 1).Value = 0
cmd.Parameters("@VAR_error").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

sqlConnection1.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

As I stated earlier, 80 to 90% of the time this works fine. During heavy use any number of the apps freeze, with some or all eventually dropping with the error message "stored procedure failed". I suspect the issue is not with the stored procedure but with the ability to connect to the server. Although I can rule out nothing at this time.

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in a `try-catch` block and adding some retry logic when you get this exception?

Comment: mjw - Yes, in the stored procedure, but it never seemed to hit it.  That is what is causing me to think that it is not the stored procedure.  I did set the IIS server to create a error log on the site hoping that I might get more info.  Of course It didn't error out today.

Comment: Is there a code to close sql connection? The code shared doesn’t seem to close connection or dispose connection objects.

Comment: Mohan, It is my understanding that the close connection command is redundant.  I have it commented out because it caused another problem when it was active.

Comment: While watching the Activity monitor on the SQL Server, we have seen a large number of connections that open during the rush.  We timed them and they appear to stay open for 500 seconds.  Not sure where that time limit is set.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer. After some research, I think the problem was hitting a limit on the connection pool.  I made a change to the asp.net VB code that calls the Stored procedure.  I added a using block with a Try/Catch inside.  then added the SQLConnection.Close .  So far with multiple hits in a short period there were only two sessions created on the Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to ASP.NET VB code to include the Using and try/catch command.  The web app has been working without issue since moved to live.

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SLDB;Initial catalog=SyteLine_AWP;Persist Security Info=True)        
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim parm As New SqlParameter()

Server.ClearError()

Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError

parm.Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
parm.ParameterName = "ReturnValue"

cmd.Parameters.Add(parm)
cmd.CommandText = "AWP_TimeClock_Web"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAR_badge_num", badgenum)
cmd.Parameters("@VAR_badge_num").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAR_term_id", TermID)
cmd.Parameters("@VAR_term_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

cmd.Parameters.Add("@VAR_emp_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = ""
cmd.Parameters("@VAR_emp_name").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

cmd.Parameters.Add("@VAR_error", SqlDbType.Int, 1).Value = 0
cmd.Parameters("@VAR_error").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

Using cmd

    Try

        sqlConnection1.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch err As Exception

        error_code = "5"

    End Try

End Using

sqlConnection1.Close()
```